# Sticky Notes not saving in 14.04

Tags: notes

I recently re-install Ubuntu 14.04 and ran all the updates it asked for.

After adding the sticky-notes to the menu bar,from the "add to pannel" options,   any note that I put on the desktop is not saved when I log out or reboot.

I did save the ~/gnome2/stickynotes-applet  file from the previous install,  and was hoping to put it back on this one,  but there is no gnome2 directory.

I have also noticed that the previous version is 3.8.1 and the current version is 3.5.92.

Side note if it helps,  I am using gnome-session-fallback, which I also used on the previous install.  I just don't like Unity.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Have you figured out how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Gnote](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/gnote-is-a-lightweight-tomboy-alternative-with-similar-functionality/).You can found it on software center.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  That's a workaround.  Not a solution.